# Seamless Mosaic with "waved" Text - ISO Software

Tags: images

I want to make a nice background that is a seamless mosaic of "waved" text.
Do you know any software with which I can do this?

An example what I mean is attached:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Adobe Illustrator is just three steps:

1. Create a path and apply a **Zig Zag** effect:

[image: Zig Zag]

2. Expand this path and use the **Type on a Path Tool** to type the text:

[image: Type on a Path]

3. Make a Pattern:

[image: Pattern]

You can use this pattern to fill any shape type:

[image]